# How to add facebook like button to contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I want to add facebook like button to wordpress contact form 7, but i don't know how..I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Regards,
Batalov

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write HTML in contact form 7 or you can place facebook like button shortcode in that.